# Storing Text file or folder in a header file and retrieve the data

Tags: java, file, header

How to Store Value stored in a folder/Text file in a header file and import it again to the program without the use of external memory or drives

This code gives me a incremented value each time when I run it and stores the value in a file. But I need to store the text file in the header itself rather than drives/external storage. So do we have any storage  headers that I can use it instead of drives

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test1 = new Test();

        test1.doMethod();

    }

    public int getCount() {

        int count = 0;
        try {
            if (!new File("d:\\myCount.txt").exists())
                return 1;
            else {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("d:\\myCount.txt")));
                String s = br.readLine();
                count = Integer.parseInt(s);
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void putCount(int count) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("d:\\myCount.txt")));
            bw.write(Integer.toString(count));
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doMethod()       //Put Method//
    {
        int count = getCount();
        if (count < 10000) {
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0000");
            System.out.println(" ID:" + nf.format(count));
            count++;
            putCount(count);

        } else if (count >= 10000)
            System.out.print("NO VACCANCY");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *header files*?

Comment: packages and import them

Comment: A header file is *different* from a package. Are you understanding your own question?